# How do I make a for loop that increase the end of my WPF image name?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, for-loop, visibility

I want to make only some of my images visible, depending on a value.

When you type a number into a textbox eg. 10 I want 10 images to be visible.

Here is some of my code to show what I mean:

One of the images with given name:

```
<Image x:Name="Image_Number1" Source="{StaticResource ImageNo2}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

My for-loop when the content of the textbox is given (this is the part im wondering about, something like):

```
for (int i = 0; i < TextboxContent; i++)
{
     Image_Number(TextboxContent).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Of course the line Image_Number(TextboxContent).Visibility = Visibility.Visible; doesen't compile.

I want to make it compile in a way that adds the TextboxContent to the end of the image name.
If the value of my textbox is 10 it sets the visibility of Image_Number1,2,3...10 to visible.
What would be a good solution for this problem?
Any suggestion is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FindName` method:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= TextboxContent; i++) {
 var img = FindName("Image_Number" + i) as FrameworkElement;
 if(img != null) img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: NB: `for (int i = 1; i <= TextboxContent; i++)` if doing 1 to 10 as opposed to 0 to 9.

Comment: @JohnLBevan what do you mean? the main idea is not the for loop, the important thing is using `FindName` method. The OP should understand what `TextBoxContent` should be. Also I can see there is a name `Image_Number0` in the OP's code, but right under that he said this `Image_Number1,2,3...10`, so looks like he just mis-stated something, but again the important thing is using `FindName`.

Comment: @JohnLBevan he edited his code, however the for-loop is still the same. Anyway from what I understand, the main OP's problem is not the for-loop, I believe he knows how to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks! The perfect solution to my problem. You just made my day :)

Comment: What i needed was the FindName method.

Comment: @KingKing agreed; my comment's just a side note for completeness, given the example image names used in the question; your answer is correct and solves his issue.